# Ubuntu Mate Bug Kicks Me Out to Login

Tags: multiple-monitors, login, google-chrome, hdmi, mate

Okay, so I run 22.04 Ubuntu Mate. I actually can't find out how to get Ubuntu to tell me more specs for the machine and it was gifted years ago, so I don't know. I believe it's an ASUS ex-windows laptop, but all it has on it is Mate now.

The actual main monitor (LVDS-1 output) is completely broken and detached (I even cut the wires), and I learned a lot about how to get it to ignore the broken screen and only run via my HDMI-1 output.

I have a set of commands that run in my .bashrc file in the root user which helps this at present. They are as such:

`xrandr --output  HDMI-1 --auto --primary && xrandr --output LVDS-1 --off`

and I have this aliased to `screenfix` for convenience, kind of just as an extra precaution since I don't know what I'm doing.

So in my eyes, as an almost total beginner, I feel I've come a long way, but I'm running into other problems.

So far, all of this is context which may be relevant (and may not be).

---

Now to the point.

When I was running Google Chrome, every time I clicked on a tab in Chrome, the whole GUI would crash and take me out to Ubuntu Mate's login screen, ending the previous session, I guess. I did a bunch of reading around and trying different things, and eventually just uninstalled Chrome. My problems appeared to be fixed.

However, a little bit ago I was re-adjusting the size of a terminal open on the screen (or was it another similar app?) and it did the same thing. I was kicked out to the login screen. I've tried to read up on similar incidents and heard that people uninstalling synergy or using a different OS has helped, but I don't know what synergy is and would like to keep this OS if possible.

Any suggestions? [Let me know if I left something important out.]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "kicked out" suggests a *desktop crash*. If you really want to know what crashed and why, look for a .crash file in /var/crash. It will tell you exactly what happened in highly technical detail. If the crash can be reproduced reliably, file a bug report and attach the .crash file...alternately, if you get the "*oops, something went wrong*" dialog, simply agree to send the report.

Comment: I think I did get the "something went wrong" dialog, at least for the browser crashing, and I sent that. I'll look for a .crash file

Comment: Is this what I'm looking for?

``` _usr_bin_caffeine.1000.crash```
```_usr_bin_caffeine.1000.upload```
```_usr_bin_caffeine.1000.uploaded```
```_usr_bin_lsb_release.1000.crash```
...
```_usr_bin_torbrowser-launcher.1000.upload```
```_usr_bin_torbrowser-launcher.1000.uploaded```
```_usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_brisk-menu_brisk-menu.1000.crash```
```_usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_brisk-menu_brisk-menu.1000.upload```
```_usr_lib_x86_64-linux-gnu_brisk-menu_brisk-menu.1000.uploaded```
```_usr_lib_xorg_Xorg.0.crash ```
I cut some out there, but something tells me I'm close

Comment: Okay, I'll update the original question with the contents of the xorg crash file --scratch that, it's many, many lines long. What am I looking for?

Comment: Look at the file creation date of each crash file. If you want to know about a crash from today, look for a file created today. Most folks can't USE a crash file (you're not diagnosing the underlying cause and fixing the bug); it's enough for most folks to know that caffeine or Xorg was the culprit, and that the crash was reported. Yes, it's really long -- I warned you about lots of technical detail. If you reported it, then you did your part.

Comment: Okay, that makes a lot of sense. And what if the issue continues - I might just have to run a different OS or reinstall or something?

[I'll check to see if caffeine or torbrowser might need to be reinstalled or something]

Comment: Shoot, now it did it to me with Firefox tabs...

Comment: From what you have shown so far, there is no single "issue" yet. If application X consistently crashes when you do actions A, B, and C, then you file a bug report since you have a way for a developer to reproduce the problem. If ten different applications crash unpredictably and unreproducibly, then you simply have bad luck: Insufficent data for a useful solution. If unlucky, then best advice we can offer is to keep close to a stock install of Ubuntu and shy away from third-party add-ons for a while. If you decide to try another OS, the advice would be the same.

Comment: If you have a lot of crashes, then put on your detective hat and look for patterns in your usage. Recognize that most patterns you see will be irrelevant (humans are very good at false association), but you might spot something useful: "Oh, it only happens while Facebook is running." "Oh, it only happens on Fridays". You can dig deep into the crash reports after you have the skills to understand them in a couple years. But who knows? Maybe the answer is shouting at you from in there in big letters "ERROR." Can't hurt to look. Also review your logs in /var/log and journalctl.

Comment: Thanks! I feel those are very helpful replies. I will try to go by that.